# Word or expression for saying that "I have found another different interest unexpectedly"

Tags: word-request, expressions

Is there a word for saying that I have found another different interest unexpectedly? Suppose that I was interested in say, Biology yesterday but today when I dabbled in Chemistry it also caught my interest (: made me interested) and therefore I got interested in Chemistry *unexpectedly*. Is there an expression for that?

In my own research I found **stumble on Chemistry** but most dictionaries say that that is more of *discovering something* than *becoming interested in something* ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stumble%20across%2Fon%2Fonto%2Fupon)).

Is there any expression for what I am intending to say?

Comment: Chemistry *engrossed* you or *caught/grabbed your interest/attention*.

Answer (score 1):

You can discover new interests by accident, so to "stumble on" something works.

The dictionary page you've linked to says:

> *to find or learn about (something) unexpectedly*

which describes finding a new interest when you didn't expect it.